# Return json file in a view

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse

In a view I create new file with:

```
sys.stdout = open(backup_name, 'w')
call_command('dumpdata')
```

How can I now return this file to user?

I tried to change mimetype in HttpResponse to 'application/json' but how can I add file content to response?

Or maybe there is other way to return file?

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy/link/call the dumpdata code related to model serialization, and dump it directly into the response, so you avoid permission problems and filesystem pollution. Content-disposition and mimetype still applies.

Remember anyway that dumpdata *can* be a lenghty process, so you are exposed to timeouts.

Comment: How about an example?

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a bit late, but I found this a useful starting point so I thought others could benefit from what I found too.

For a small file, if you place the json file in a template folder, django can find it and you can return it with `render_to_response`:

```
return render_to_response(data_file,mimetype='application/json')
```

I found this to be problematic for large datasets on certain browsers.  I would get the error `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`.  An alternative approach fixed this.

First you must create full path to your file.  Use the PROJECT_ROOT variable (defined by `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` in settings.py).  To access this and the os methods you must `import settings, os` in views.py.  Once you have this file location you can return it using the code below:

```
backup_path = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "templates", "json_dumps", "large_file.json")
return HttpResponse(open(backup_path, 'r'),content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf8')
```

I found this worked well for even very large files.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have it:

```
response = HttpResponse(open(backup_path, "r"), mimetype='application/json', )
response['Content-Disposition'] = "filename=%s" % backup_name"
```

After saving file on disc I open it for reading and set file name in response.

Anyone has another idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to return a dictionary as a json file. Here is my solution:

```
import json
import cStringIO as StringIO
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
from django.http import HttpResponse

data_string = json.dumps(data)
json_file = StringIO.StringIO()
json_file.write(data_string)
json_file.seek(0)

wrapper = FileWrapper(json_file)
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/json')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachement; filename=dump.json'
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is (thanks to saverio):

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/json', )
response['Content-Disposition'] = "filename=%s" % backup_name
sys.stdout = response
call_command('dumpdata')
```